# Javascript Shipping Calculator Not Grabbing Input

Tags: javascript, input, calculator

I am getting the headache of a lifetime. I'm not too great with Javascript so I have no idea what's going on. I'm supposed to be coding a text box that when a price is entered and submitted it will calculate the shipping and tell you the total. Everything is working except for the fact that the typed value isn't being set. So the price seems to be permanently set at NaN no matter what is inputted. What am I doing wrong? D:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" name="number" onsubmit='window.alert("Your total is $" + total + ".");'>
      <input type="text" name="purchasePrice" placeholder="0.00" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
      /* <![CDATA[ */
      var price = parseFloat(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
      var shipping = parseFloat(calculateShipping(price));
      var total = price + shipping;
      function calculateShipping(price) {
        if (price <= 25) {
          return 1.5;
        } else {
          return price * 10 / 100
        }
      }
      /* ]]> */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample which may help you

```
<input id="amount" type="text" name="purchasePrice" placeholder="0.00" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />

var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

function calculateShipping() {
    var price = parseFloat(amount.value) || 0;

    if (price <= 25) {
        alert("Your total is $" + 1.5);
    } else {
        alert("Your total is $" + (price * 10 / 100));
    }
}

submit.addEventListener("click", calculateShipping, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/cf3zA/)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript code runs before it knows price... so anything *,+ NaN is... NaN.

You should call calculation of total while submit is clicked, f.ex. this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

 <body>

<form method="post" name="number" onsubmit='calculateTotal()'>
<input type="text" name="purchasePrice" placeholder="0.00" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */

function calculateTotal() {
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
    var shipping = parseFloat(calculateShipping(price));
    var total = price+shipping;

    window.alert("Your total is $" + total + ".");
}


function calculateShipping(price) {
    if (price <= 25) {
        return 1.5; }
    else {
        return price * 10/100 }
    }

/* ]]> */
 </script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Ohman, thank you so much, that works! I feel ridiculous for not having though to do that.

Comment: It's a kind of quick-n-dirty solution :) If you are going to get serious into js try to play f.ex. with jQuery like @Ghodmode recommended

Comment: Inline javascript is not good practice. If your going to get serious into javascript then you need to learn javascript and then through experience decide when 3rd party libraries (underscore, jquery, protocol, mootools, dojo, etc) are appropriate.

Comment: @Xotic750 I totally agree, it is not the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an event handler that fires when the user enters a value.

```
<form method="post" name="number" onsubmit='window.alert("Your total is $" + total + ".");'>
<label for="purchasePrice">Price:</label>
<input type="text" name="purchasePrice" id="purchasePrice" placeholder="0.00" />
<br>
<label for="shipping">Shipping:</label>
<input type="text" name="shipping" id="shipping" disabled>
<!-- <input type="submit" value="submit" /> -->
</form>

<script>
    var price;
    var shipping = parseFloat(calculateShipping(price));
    var total = price+shipping;

    function calculateShipping(price) {
        if (price <= 25) {
            return 1.5; }
        else {
            return price * 10/100;
        }
    }

    var pp = document.getElementById("purchasePrice");
    pp.onkeyup = function(e){
        price = calculateShipping(this.value);
        document.getElementById("shipping").value = price;
    };
</script>
```

This kind of thing really is easier with a library like jQuery.  It also handles the differences between browser implementations for attaching event handlers.